# Unix command to delete 1st,2nd and 5th character from each line of a file?

Tags: sed, awk, cut

For example :let us consider my file contains 100 lines in which i need to delete 1st,2nd and 5th character from each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try doing this

```
cut -c 3,4,6- file
```

See :

[man cut](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cut)

### Sample Output

```
$ cat file
1abcdefgh 
2abcdefgh
3abcdefgh

$ cut -c 3,4,6- file
bcefgh 
bcefgh
bcefgh
```

Comment: I'll try and let u knw the result.

Answer (score 0):

you could give this a try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{$5=$1=$2=""}1' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  cat file
12345678foo
12345678foo
12345678foo
12345678foo
12345678foo

kent$  awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{$5=$1=$2=""}1' file
34678foo
34678foo
34678foo
34678foo
34678foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all your effort
I tried d first one and its working fine
 $ cut -c 3,4,6- file